# Lotus notes how to not take row in to view if field in column is empty

Tags: formula, lotus-notes, lotusscript

If I generate a view with 2 columns (name and email)  if email of a row is empty how can I tell notes to not take the row in to the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend the formula in view's View Selection Formula like

```
SELECT Form="Person" & EMail != ""
```

assuming view shows documents of form "Person" and the email is in field "EMail".

[image]